# How can I use fancy string date indexing with MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's imagine I have the following `DataFrame`

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "id": [1, 1, 1], 
    "date": ["2020-1-1", "2020-1-4", "2020-2-3"], 
    "value": [1, 2, 3]
})
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], format="%Y-%m-%d")

# This is
#    id       date  value
# 0   1 2020-01-01      1
# 1   1 2020-01-04      2
# 2   1 2020-02-03      3
```

Now, having the `date` column as index I can index a month like this:

```py
df.set_index("date")["2020-01"]
# Output:
#             id  value
# date                 
# 2020-01-01   1      1
# 2020-01-04   1      2
```

But having a MultiIndex, I can't manage to use this feature. I tried using slices like:

```py
df.set_index(["id", "date"])[:, "2020-01"]
```

Which raises a

```
TypeError: '(slice(None, None, None), '2020-01')' is an invalid key
```

Is there a clean way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible, but need `IndexSlice`, because `DatetimeIndex` is in second level:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
print (df.set_index(["id", "date"]).loc[idx[:, '2020-01'], :])
               value
id date             
1  2020-01-01      1
   2020-01-04      2
```

If `DatetimeIndex` in first level:

```
print (df.set_index(["date", "id"]).loc['2020-01'])
               value
date       id       
2020-01-01 1       1
2020-01-04 1       2
```

[DatetimeIndex partial string indexing also works on a DataFrame with a MultiIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html#indexing):

```
In [111]: dft2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(20, 1),
   .....:                     columns=['A'],
   .....:                     index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
   .....:                         [pd.date_range('20130101', periods=10, freq='12H'),
   .....:                          ['a', 'b']]))
   .....:
```

---

```
In [112]: dft2
Out[112]: 
                              A
2013-01-01 00:00:00 a -0.298694
                    b  0.823553
2013-01-01 12:00:00 a  0.943285
                    b -1.479399
2013-01-02 00:00:00 a -1.643342
...                         ...
2013-01-04 12:00:00 b  0.069036
2013-01-05 00:00:00 a  0.122297
                    b  1.422060
2013-01-05 12:00:00 a  0.370079
                    b  1.016331

[20 rows x 1 columns]

In [113]: dft2.loc['2013-01-05']
Out[113]: 
                              A
2013-01-05 00:00:00 a  0.122297
                    b  1.422060
2013-01-05 12:00:00 a  0.370079
                    b  1.016331
```

---

```
In [114]: idx = pd.IndexSlice

In [115]: dft2 = dft2.swaplevel(0, 1).sort_index()


In [116]: dft2.loc[idx[:, '2013-01-05'], :]
Out[116]: 
                              A
a 2013-01-05 00:00:00  0.122297
  2013-01-05 12:00:00  0.370079
b 2013-01-05 00:00:00  1.422060
  2013-01-05 12:00:00  1.016331
```

Answer (score 0):

To do what you are trying to do, one way is to specify the axis argument to .loc to interpret the passed slicers on a single axis.

```
df.set_index(["id", "date"]).loc(axis=0)[:, "2020-01"]
```